# How to Show Preview in PictureBox?

Tags: c#, directshow.net

my is too record video from webcam using DirectshowLib and c# but during video recoding video preview is also be shown so for this i have done following steps

1.i got the available video device

1. init. IFilterGrapth2 object by using `Graph = (IFilterGraph2)new FilterGraph();`
2. init. ICaptureGraphBuilder2 object by using `captureGraph = (ICaptureGraphBuilder2)new CaptureGraphBuilder2();`

4.filter grapth is set to ICaptureGraphBuilder2 object `captureGraph.SetFiltergraph(Graph);`

1. and then added soursefilterformoniker() and outputfilename()

The full code is as below.it does not any error but it opens preview window separately;i want to show preview on picture box..

**how to preview window in picturebox?**

here is my full code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DirectShowLib;
using DirectShowLib.DMO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.IO;

namespace Cam_Recording_V1_directshow.net_
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string captureDeviceName = string.Empty;
        IFilterGraph2 Graph = null;
        IMediaControl m_mediaCtrl = null;
        public List<DsDevice> AvailableVideoInputDevices { get; private set; }
        IAMVideoProcAmp vpa;
        [DllImport("olepro32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true)]
        private static extern int OleCreatePropertyFrame(IntPtr hwndOwner, int x, int y,
            string lpszCaption, int cObjects,
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] ref object ppUnk,
            int cPages, IntPtr pPageClsID, int lcid, int dwReserved, IntPtr pvReserved);
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            IBaseFilter capFilter = null;
            IBaseFilter asfWriter = null;
            IFileSinkFilter pTmpSink = null;
            ICaptureGraphBuilder2 captureGraph = null;
            object o;

            //
            //Get list of video devices
            //
            AvailableVideoInputDevices = new List<DsDevice>();
            DsDevice[] videoInputDevices = DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            AvailableVideoInputDevices.AddRange(videoInputDevices);
            if (AvailableVideoInputDevices.Count > 0)
            {
                //
                //init capture graph
                //
                Graph = (IFilterGraph2)new FilterGraph();
                captureGraph = (ICaptureGraphBuilder2)new CaptureGraphBuilder2();

                //
                //sets filter object from graph
                //
                captureGraph.SetFiltergraph(Graph);
                //
                //which device will use graph setting
                //
                Graph.AddSourceFilterForMoniker(AvailableVideoInputDevices.First().Mon, null, AvailableVideoInputDevices.First().Name, out capFilter);
                captureDeviceName = AvailableVideoInputDevices.First().Name;
                #region WMV
                //
                //sets output file name,and file type
                //
                captureGraph.SetOutputFileName(MediaSubType.Asf, /*DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()  +".wmv"*/ "test.wmv", out asfWriter, out pTmpSink);
                //
                //configure which video setting is used by graph
                //                
                IConfigAsfWriter lConfig = asfWriter as IConfigAsfWriter;
                Guid cat = new Guid("8C45B4C7-4AEB-4f78-A5EC-88420B9DADEF");
                lConfig.ConfigureFilterUsingProfileGuid(cat);
                #endregion                      
                captureGraph.RenderStream(PinCategory.Preview, MediaType.Video, capFilter, null, null);

                captureGraph.RenderStream(PinCategory.Capture, MediaType.Video, capFilter, null, asfWriter);
                m_mediaCtrl = Graph as IMediaControl;
                m_mediaCtrl.Run();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Video Capture Device Not Found!!");
                button1.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this using VMR9.  I added a VMR9 filter in the Graph. and many more.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on how you actually connected the Image and the VMR9 filter?