# Video Streaming and Recording st the same time Using Directshow.Net in c#?

Tags: c#, directshow.net

i want to record video through webcam using Directshow.Net.i can able to record the video using ASFWriter but along with recording i want to stream the video to an PC in the LAN..i tried this..

i run project which i develop for recording the video this is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DirectShowLib;
using DirectShowLib.DMO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.IO;

namespace Cam_Recording_V1_directshow.net_
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string captureDeviceName = string.Empty;
    IFilterGraph2 Graph = null;
    IMediaControl m_mediaCtrl = null;
    public List<DsDevice> AvailableVideoInputDevices { get; private set; }
    IAMVideoProcAmp vpa;
    [DllImport("olepro32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern int OleCreatePropertyFrame(IntPtr hwndOwner, int x, int y,
        string lpszCaption, int cObjects,
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] ref object ppUnk,
        int cPages, IntPtr pPageClsID, int lcid, int dwReserved, IntPtr pvReserved);
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        IBaseFilter capFilter = null;
        IBaseFilter asfWriter = null;
        IFileSinkFilter pTmpSink = null;
        ICaptureGraphBuilder2 captureGraph = null;
        object o;

        //
        //Get list of video devices
        //
        AvailableVideoInputDevices = new List<DsDevice>();
        DsDevice[] videoInputDevices = DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        AvailableVideoInputDevices.AddRange(videoInputDevices);
        if (AvailableVideoInputDevices.Count > 0)
        {
            //
            //init capture graph
            //
            Graph = (IFilterGraph2)new FilterGraph();
            captureGraph = (ICaptureGraphBuilder2)new CaptureGraphBuilder2();

            //
            //sets filter object from graph
            //
            captureGraph.SetFiltergraph(Graph);
            //
            //which device will use graph setting
            //
            Graph.AddSourceFilterForMoniker(AvailableVideoInputDevices.First().Mon, null, AvailableVideoInputDevices.First().Name, out capFilter);
            captureDeviceName = AvailableVideoInputDevices.First().Name;
            #region WMV
            //
            //sets output file name,and file type
            //
            captureGraph.SetOutputFileName(MediaSubType.Asf, /*DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()  +".wmv"*/ "test.wmv", out asfWriter, out pTmpSink);
            //
            //configure which video setting is used by graph
            //                
            IConfigAsfWriter lConfig = asfWriter as IConfigAsfWriter;
            Guid cat = new Guid("8C45B4C7-4AEB-4f78-A5EC-88420B9DADEF");
            lConfig.ConfigureFilterUsingProfileGuid(cat);
            #endregion                      
            captureGraph.RenderStream(PinCategory.Preview, MediaType.Video, capFilter, null, null);

            captureGraph.RenderStream(PinCategory.Capture, MediaType.Video, capFilter, null, asfWriter);
            m_mediaCtrl = Graph as IMediaControl;
            m_mediaCtrl.Run();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Video Capture Device Not Found!!");
            button1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

this will start the video recording..after that i run [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80413/Streaming-Server-using-Direct-Show-and-Windows-Med) project exe from "Release" folder it will gives error like "media run failed"

Now My question **is it possible to do recording and live streaming at the same time?**

If Yes,then please guide me through this..and also please guide me on my this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926178/how-to-show-preview-in-picturebox) also

Comment: did you ever achieve this?

Comment: @KristjanKica Yes, as said in answer I have created graph manually by using [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Viscomsoft.DirectshowRTMPStreamingFilter) Streaming Filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should build the graph manually. The graph should look like the follwing diagramm. You can test the Graph using GraphEdt. This also helps for getting the Guid and PinNames.

```
VideoSource -> SmartTee -> StreamingFilter
                        -> CaptureFilter
```

The DirectShowLib provides all functions you need to do build the graph.

You can create the filter like you did in your example. The SmartTee filter can be created directly.

You should connect the filter using graph.Connect() method. Using this, you can build the following graph using the SmartTee Filter. SmartTee filter should be available on your system and provides two output pins, one for capturing and one for preview. You should use preveiw pin for the Streaming and the capture pin for the Capture filter.

You can get the required Pin for the connect method using the following function:

```
    public IPin GetPin(IBaseFilter filter, string pinname)
    {
        IEnumPins epins;
        int hr = filter.EnumPins(out epins);
        if(hr < 0)
            return null;
        IntPtr fetched = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(4);
        IPin[] pins = new IPin[1];
        epins.Reset();
        while (epins.Next(1, pins, fetched) == 0)
        {
            PinInfo pinfo;
            pins[0].QueryPinInfo(out pinfo);
            bool found = (pinfo.name == pinname);
            DsUtils.FreePinInfo(pinfo);
            if (found)
                return pins[0];
        }
        return null;
    }
```

At the end, you have to start the graph and everything will work hopefully. It is important taht you check the hr code after every method call for error handling.

Comment: Thanks Maria for giving reply..i will try for this